# How authentication and sessions works on Twitter?

Tags: security, authentication, session, twitter, jwt

I'm trying to understand how twitter auth and session works on the web app, more particularly on storing and sending. I see that there's a cookie http only and an authentication bearer.

When I try to log in, I see requests and the first in on a service worker, and none of the requests contains my credentials... At the first time, I see tons of bundle and libs downloaded, and some are like "login.js" "logout.js".
[image]

My question is, where is the api call to know if my credentials are goods ? How my session and my jwt auth is stored. I have a httponly cookie called auth_token but when I log out, it still here !! Is there a node server between the app and the "real api server" ??? What are doing service workers here ????

A really complexe question but I can't find out tuto or explanation on it...

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the [Twitter API documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0).

Comment: Hum, that's not what I'm searching. This is a classic oauth2 token explanation. I'm don't want to know what is a jwt, I know it and oauth2 too. I'm looking for what I asked, not how I can connect a third app to twitter. My question is just to know how are stored all tokens (session, authentication) if they use cookies httponly, if they remove it on logout or if they just remove the http only param. Is there a token to identify mobile.twitter.com for example etc... What is the stack implemented by twitter on twitter, on browser only.